# Options in Settings not persisting in Stock Android 5.1.1

Tags: settings, 5.1-lollipop, vanilla-android

I've Yu Yunique which comes with stock Android 5.1.1 installed. Some options in settings though being enabled in UI View aren't actually enabled.

For instance, take `Blacklist` option. When I switch it **ON**, and come back, it still shows

> **Blacklist**
>
> Disabled

When I click on `Blacklist` again, the switch is turned **ON** indeed, just that that isn't being reflected in the previous screen, aka `Settings -> Security`

I suppose the same bug is making most of the app locks not work on my phone. For instance, CM Security repeatedly asks me to

```
"Turn on the CM Security"
```

and shows me the `Apps with usage access` option repeatedly, even though, I've already switched it on.

Being a first-time android user, I didn't expect such hurdles that too with Android Lollipop.

What's the solution to persist these changes for I suppose they're not being persisted or saved as of now?

Comment: You may need to report the issue to YU and/or CyanogenMod. Agree that android 5.1 / CyanogenOS/Mod 12.1 on YU devices is too buggy as of now :)

Comment: @BharatG no other quick fix in sight? Is that the only option?

Comment: Have you done a factory reset and see if it persists? Considering not many users having your device which is out only recently, you can only wait for a software update to get that fixed.

Comment: You could try one of quite a few custom ROMs for the Yunique. Choose something that says "stable" if possible. I'm eternally sorry to the Android Gods for having to recommend a custom ROM as a solution to a first time Android user. Google can help you in finding such ROMs and associated details. You can ask questions about other parts you have problems with.

Comment: [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/recovery-yu-yunique-yu4711-t3216745) and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/stable-semi-cm12-1-unofficial-yu-yunique-t3218072) should get you started.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury thanks for the lead, but could you also help me in finding a tuts for reliably unlocking the bootloader?